# select <tr> when checkbox is check ajax query

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, mysqli

I have a bit of a complex query. I'm looking to remove other options when the checkbox is checked on the selected item when the AJAX query results are returned. The reason for this is because currently I have to enter the entire matching result so the result is narrowed down to one item. Otherwise the user would have to put a check on the item they selected and then scroll down about half the page to click the submit button to add the item they selected on a different table.

Here is my code so far;

**trigger.js**

```
// SKU search AJAX START //
$(document).ready(function() {  

$(".tablesearch").hide();
// Search
function search() {
var query_value = $('input#barcode').val();
if(query_value !== ''){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax/inventory.php",
        data: { query: query_value },
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
            $("table#resultTable tbody").html(html);
        }
    });
}return false;    
}

$("input#barcode").on("keyup", function(e) {
// Set Timeout
clearTimeout($.data(this, 'timer'));

// Set Search String
var search_string = $(this).val();

// Do Search
if (search_string == '') {
    $(".tablesearch").fadeOut(300);
}else{
    $(".tablesearch").fadeIn(300);
    $(this).data('timer', setTimeout(search, 100));
};
});
});
// SKU search AJAX END //
```

**db-ajax.php**

```
<?php
// Credentials
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbname = "cms";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "pass";

//  Connection
global $test_db;

$ajax_db = new mysqli();
$ajax_db->connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
$ajax_db->set_charset("utf8");

//  Check Connection
if ($ajax_db->connect_errno) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $ajax_db->connect_error);
exit();
} 
?>
```

**inventory.php**

```
<?php
require_once "db-ajax.php";
// Output HTML formats
$html =  "<tr>";
$html .= "<td>skuString</td>";
$html .= "<td>catString</td>";
$html .= "<td>descString</td>"; 
$html .= "<td>stockString</td>";
$html .= "<td>priceString</td>";
$html .= "<td><input class='checkBoxes' type='checkbox' name='checkBoxArray[]' value='skuIdString'></td>";
$html .= "</tr>";

// Get the Search
$search_string = preg_replace("/[^,-\/\sA-Za-z0-9_]/", " ", $_POST['query']);
$search_string = $ajax_db->real_escape_string($search_string);

// Check if length is more than 1 character
if (strlen($search_string) >= 1 && $search_string !== ' ') {
$query  = 'SELECT s_id, sku_number, category, description, price, in_stock ';
$query .= 'FROM parts_stock AS a JOIN items AS b ON a.stock_id = b.s_id ';
$query .= 'WHERE sku_number LIKE "%'.$search_string.'%" OR category LIKE "%'.$search_string.'%"';

// Do the search
$result = $ajax_db->query($query);
while($results = $result->fetch_array()) {
    $result_array[] = $results;

}

// Check for results
if (isset($result_array)) {
    foreach ($result_array as $result) {
    // Output strings and highlight the matches
     $d_sku = preg_replace("/".$search_string."/i", "<b>".$search_string."</b>", $result['sku_number']);
     $d_cat   = $result['category'];
     $d_desc  = $result['description'];
     $d_stock = $result['in_stock'];    
     $d_price = $result['price'];
     $s_id    = $result['s_id'];

    // Replace the items into above HTML
    $o = str_replace('skuString', $d_sku, $html);
    $o = str_replace('catString', $d_cat, $o);
    $o = str_replace('descString', $d_desc, $o);
    $o = str_replace('stockString', $d_stock, $o);    
    $o = str_replace('priceString', $d_price, $o);
    $o = str_replace('skuIdString', $s_id, $o);

    // Output it
    echo($o);
        }
    }else{
    // Replace for no results
    $o = str_replace('skuString', '<span class="label label-danger">No SKUs Found</span>', $html);
    $o = str_replace('catString', '', $o);
    $o = str_replace('descString', '', $o);
    $o = str_replace('stockString', '', $o);
    $o = str_replace('priceString', '', $o);
    $o = str_replace('skuIdString', '', $o);

    // Output
    echo($o);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Are you looking for a javascript DOM thing, or PHP / Ajax solution? Your question is not very clear what exactly you need to fix.

Comment: Sorry if i wasn't clear on this. But I'm looking for a PHP/AJAX solution preferred.

Comment: So your `select <tr> when checkbox is check...` you mean want to select from your database via `query` just so it shows only the selection `onchange`?

Comment: Yes. When I query there are many results provided. The result I'm looking for is: when the checkbox is check remove other possible results. I guess this could be done with an onchange, not sure.